# unable to pass data form tableview to viewcontroller in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

hi I'm new to iOS development. in my application i have fetch datas form outside database and i viewed in tableview so now i have created on detailviewcontroller. to give clear view about the data but its not working.

the code i used.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    detailviewpoliticalViewController *dvc =[[detailviewpoliticalViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"dvc" bundle:nil];

    fieldpolitical * ff =[eventarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    dvc.eve =ff.title;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];
}
```

this is the declaration and and initialization of the data in .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface detailviewpoliticalViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *eve;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *event;
@end
```

in .m file in viewload

```
event.text = self.eve;
```

Comment: "eve" is that declared as property in detailviewpoliticalViewController?

Comment: You really should use longer variable names. By reading `dvc.eve = ff.title;` it is impossible to know what you are talking about.

Comment: are you sure ff.title is not null?

Comment: What isn't working exactly ? Is it not pushing the new view controller ? Or is the new view controller empty ?

Comment: yes its not pushing the view controller

Comment: please format your code next time, i just edited it for you

Comment: thanks sr.richie next time i will make sure it wont happen

Answer (score 0):

I think ff.title is not getting any value, because rest of the things you are doing is fine. Please try to print ff.title before passing it to next view.

Answer (score 0):

First check dvc is your nib(xib) name.

Make exact nib name i thing your nib name should be detailviewpoliticalViewController. i checked from starting if your xib name is correct then tell me i will check next next lines

```
detailviewpoliticalViewController *dvc =[[detailviewpoliticalViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"dvc" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: ok did you check what value is comming in ff.title. please print it. also print  self.eve.

Comment: im new to ios can pls tell me how to do print the value

Comment: use  NSLog(@"title is %@",ff.title); &NSLog(@"passed value is %@", self.eve); put the second Nslog is in  detailviewpoliticalViewController

Comment: hi imac sir i have few problems if i can get ur skye or gmail id means it will be lot better for me because fresher now working in a small company right now im using this imac for just past 15 days only can pls help me